# StreamingKMeans setSeed()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I need to train StreamingKMeans with a specific value for seed. When I run

```
val km = new StreamingKMeans(3, 1.0, "points")
km.setRandomCenters(10, 0.5)
val newmodel = km.latestModel.update(featureVectors, 1.0, "points")

val prediction3 = id_features.map(x=> (x._1, newmodel.predict(x._2)))
```

it works fine. But when I am trining to use sedSeed:

```
km.setRandomCenters(10, 0.5).setSeed(6250L)
```

I am getting an error:

value setSeed is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans

How can I set the seed in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that there is no `setSeed` member of `org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans` (which you can verify from the [*API* docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans); oddly, this method does exist for the `KMeans` class, but not for `StreamingKMeans`).

However, all is not lost... ;-)

The `setRandomCenters` method takes 3 parameters, with the third being the random seed. It's value defaults to `Utils.random.nextLong`. To do what you want, you should change that line from:

```scala
km.setRandomCenters(10, 0.5).setSeed(6250L)
```

to:

```scala
km.setRandomCenters(10, 0.5, 6250L)
```

**UPDATE**: Incidentally, *Spark* utilizes the *functional programming* paradigm. Consequently, calling a method such as `.setRandomCenters` on an `StreamingKMeans` instance typically does not modify (or *mutate*) that instance. Rather, it creates a new instance with the modifications applied to it.

In your code, you effectively discard the changes made by `SetRandomCenters`, because you do not store the result. Your code ought to look something more like this:

```scala
val km = new StreamingKMeans(3, 1.0, "points").setRandomCenters(10, 0.5)

val newmodel = km.latestModel.update(featureVectors, 1.0, "points")

val prediction3 = id_features.map(x=> (x._1, newmodel.predict(x._2)))
```

Comment: "Spark utilizes the functional programming paradigm. Consequently, calling a method such as (...) on an (...) instance typically does not modify (or mutate) that instance" - that might be true for "data structures" (`RDD`, `Dataset`) and legacy MLlib API, but it is strictly false, in ML API. Just saying...

Comment: @user10465355 Yeah. Having looked at the code, this _does_ mutate the instance.